# How is it possible to initialize the Junit5 Mocks annotated with @Mock before each test using MockitoExtension?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I would like to create some Junit test using the annotation @Mock and MockitoExtension.
Something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {
    @Mock
    MyObject mock;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        ..
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        ..
    }
```

How can I tell to MockitoExtension that it has to create the mock before each test execution to isolate them?
I would like to avoid that the first executed test defining a behavior for the mock with `when(mock.doSomething()).then(returnSomething())` will not influence the other tests by resetting the mock)

Comment: Mockito by default creates new mocks for each test - exactly to avoid unwanted coupling between tests. Why do you think it reuses mocks?

Comment: @ThomasKläger perfect, thanks a lot for your answer. 
I thought test were reusing the mock because I didn't found specific info concerning it and when I see a global variable subconsciously I assume it impacts all the (test)methods!

Answer (score 0):

It's not just Mockito that is reinitialized, it's standard JUnit behavior.  A new instance of your `Test` class is created for each method.  So this creates isolation between each test for anything you set up as instance members, including Mockito instances.

You can imagine your test is run like this:

```java
Test instance1 = new Test();
instance1.test1();

Test instance2 = new Test();
instance2.test2();
```

You can set behavior for each instance using `@BeforeEach`:

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
  // this runs for every test method on a brand new scope
}
```

notice how it is an *instance* method.

If you do want "global" behavior, you use `static` methods and variables instead.  The corresponding annotations are `@BeforeAll`/`@AfterAll` which must be applied to static methods and runs once each for the whole class.